# SQL Puppy Database: Trying to make a specific query using inner joins, stuck?

Tags: mysql, database

I have a sample database I am using to learn SQL and am trying to write a query to select puppies to display the tricks that it knows given the following criteria:

Dog id & name
Trick id & name
Date learned & skill level

Here is a picture of my database diagram:

[image: dbdiagram]

Any help is really appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: I am not sure where to start I know I need to do some inner joins but the concept is confusing to me

Comment: Are you still stuck with this question? If someone has provided an answer, or a helpful response, please mark it so. It will help us help you to get to the answer you need.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should never really do select * (returning all columns), be specific of what columns you want.  This way, in the future, if a table changes and columns removed, it will immediately crash and you'll know right away why something failed vs guessing.

Next, on writing queries, use explicit joins between the tables without any consideration of criteria.  This just so you know in SQL, how the relationships work... the following will work for your diagram.  I am using "aliases" (P for puppy, PT for puppy_trick, etc) to help simplify long typing of the query.

```
select
      P.puppyID,
      P.PuppyName,
      P.Breed,
      PT.TrickID,
      PT.SkillLevel,
      PT.DateLearned,
      T.TrickName,
      TK.KennelName,
      TK.KennelAddress
   from
      Puppy P
         JOIN Puppy_Trick PT
            on P.PuppyID = PT.PuppyID
            JOIN Trick T
               on PT.TrickID = T.TrickID
               JOIN Trick_Kennel TK
                  on T.TrickID = TK.TrickID
                  JOIN Kennel K
                     on TK.TrickKennelID = K.TrickKennelID
```

Notice the formatting / alignment I have.  I find that it helps see the relation from one to the next as a chain... you can't get from Puppy to the Kennel without going through all the others.

NOW, the criteria.  Once you have the underlying how to get a-b-c-d-e relationships, what are you looking for.  You can apply that by adding "AND" criteria to the respective join to the table.  For example, if you are looking for trick of "Jump through hoop", that is associated with the Trick table for the actual description, so from the above

```
Join Trick T
   on PT.TrickID = T.TrickID
   AND T.TrickName = 'Jump through hoop'
```

If you want something for a particular puppy, since that is the root-level (ie: first table in the query), that would add a "WHERE" clause at the end of all the above...

(so, after the join to Kennel)

```
                      JOIN Kennel K
                         on TK.TrickKennelID = K.TrickKennelID
   WHERE
      P.PuppyName = 'Spot'
```

Answer (score 0):

here is an SQL Query :

```
SELECT *
From Puppy As p, Trick as t, Pappy_Trick as pt 
Where 
p.PuppyID = pt.PuppyId AND t.TrickID = pt.TrickID
AND p.PuppyID = 'value' AND PuppyName = 'value' AND t.TrickID = 'value' AND TrickName = 'value' AND DateLearned = 'value' AND SkillLevel = 'value';
```

What's important is the first conditions in the where clause

```
p.PuppyID = pt.PuppyId AND t.TrickID = pt.TrickID
```

Which help link the 3 tables.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the linking table to get to join the Puppy and Trick tables...

```
SELECT *
FROM   Puppy AS P 
       INNER JOIN Puppy_Trick AS PT ON P.PuppyID = PT.PuppyID
       INNER JOIN Trick AS T ON T.TrickID = PT.TrickID
```

Then, instead of `SELECT *` select the fields you actually want.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Select PuppyName, TrickName
 From Puppy 
 Join Puppy_Trick
 On Puppy.PuppyID = Puppy_Trick.PuppyID
 Join Trick
 On Puppy_Trick.PuppyTrickID = Trick.TrickID
```